# Create unique ID's in VFP

Tags: uniqueidentifier, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I need to create unique record id's in VFP based on mailing information: zip5, address, lastname, firstname.  Once created, relational tables will be loaded in SQL server 7 with the unique ID's. Any suggestinos?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a GUID: [GUID entry at FoxPro Wiki](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~GUID~VFP).

And here are some [examples](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~GUIDGenerationCode).

Easiest one using WSH...

```
   * VFP 7+
   oGUID = CreateObject("scriptlet.typelib") 
   cGUID = Strextract(oGUID.GUID, "{", "}" )

   * Other VFP
   oGUID = CreateObject("scriptlet.typelib")
   cGUID = substr( oGUID.GUID, 2, 36 )
```

Answer (score 2):

VFP does have support for unique IDs - in that it has [Primary Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9w73shy(VS.80).aspx#foconvisualfoxproindextypesanchor1) (which can be based on multiple fields - but make sure the key length is fixed, so if your VFP table uses varchars you will need to pad the fields) and a table can also have [Candidate Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9w73shy(VS.80).aspx#foconvisualfoxproindextypesanchor2) (where the indexed field(s) must be unique, just like a primary key, but you can have multiple candidate indexes per table).

Either of these will enforce uniqueness in your fields, but generating a primary key based on zip5, address, lastname and firstname will be inefficient. The suggestion of GUIDs will work nicely, or if you have VFP8 or later you can use an [Autoinc column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa976850(VS.71).aspx), which is analogous to an Identity column in SQL Server.

Incidentally, unique indexes are [only used for backward compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9w73shy(VS.80).aspx#foconvisualfoxproindextypesanchor5)..

Answer (score -1):

I created my own function for that purpose to return a unique identifier. When I have a new record I just scan the database and have the function replace the unique identifier field (I call mine UID) in the database with a new uid if the record does not have one.

```
FUNCTION UIDgenerator()
   LOCAL c_UID
   LOCAL c_dump

   c_UID = STRTRAN(SYS(2015),"_","") + [-]

   c_dump = STRTRAN(SYS(2015),"_","")
   c_dump = STRTRAN(SYS(2015),"_","")
   c_dump = STRTRAN(SYS(2015),"_","")

   c_UID = c_UID + STRTRAN(SYS(2015),"_","")


   RETURN c_UID

   endfunction() &&UIDGenerator
```

You don't have to do c_dump 3 times, but I wanted the identifiers to be a little more further apart.